# How to find the newly added file within a folder?

Tags: cocoa

I just realize that, unlike in windows environment, where copying a file to a new location will change its creation date, in Mac OSX, the copied file still preserves its original creation date and modification date value.

So is there a way to find out which files were added into a specific folder after a certain point of time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Spotlight indexing is turned on on the system you want to query (by default it is) and the file is not in a network file location, files will have a kMDItemDateAdded metadata attribute after they have been added (e.g. by copying) to a folder, containing date and time on which they were added.

You can query this attribute with mdls from the terminal, or with NSMetadataQuery programmatically, or you could use some MDItem.h routines (see the code example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6931995/521923).

From the MDItem.h file: "@constant kMDItemDateAdded: This is the date that the file was moved into the current location. Not all files will have this attribute.  Not all file systems support this attribute."