# Get the Date, when the file was added to the mobile documents folder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, icloud

Is it possible/Is there a file attribute to get the date, when a file was added to the mobile documents folder/icloud?

Comment: Would it not be `NSFileCreationDate` attribute of the file look at [NSFileManager - attributesOfItemAtPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: on the mac ...

No, NSFileCreationDate would only work, if I would create new Files, but that doesn't work, if you're copying/moving files to the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer in another question here at stackoverflow:

[Where does the Finder obtain the "date added" of an item in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007186/where-does-the-finder-obtain-the-date-added-of-an-item-in-a-folder)

The date-added attribute is in the Spotlight metadata:

```
NSDate *dateAdded(NSURL *url)
{
    NSDate *rslt = nil;
    MDItemRef inspectedRef = nil;

    inspectedRef = MDItemCreateWithURL(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFURLRef)url);
    if (inspectedRef){
        CFTypeRef cfRslt = MDItemCopyAttribute(inspectedRef, (CFStringRef)@"kMDItemDateAdded");
        if (cfRslt) {
            rslt = (NSDate *)cfRslt;
        }
    }
    return rslt;
}
```